# Deleting an upvoted comment

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I'm trying to flag [a comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44820/could-dark-energy-be-heat-could-dark-matter-be-stuff-that-is-not-seen-because-o#comment92237_44825) for removal on my answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44820/could-dark-energy-be-heat-could-dark-matter-be-stuff-that-is-not-seen-because-o) question. The comment (made by Anna V) is obsolete, because I successfully managed to flag the other comments on the thread (the thread was about how to upload an image in an answer).

But I originally upvoted her comment, and now I'm unable to flag for deletion. Is this a bug or a "feature" (:P)?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's a deficiency in the comment voting/flagging system, but it's not really worth improving. See [Allow flagging a comment after upvoting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it)

You have three courses of action:

- Unupvote the comment (note that you can't reupvote if you do this). You can only unupvote if you've recently upvoted the comment
- Flag the post with a custom flag asking for comment deletion.
- Complain on meta about the comment being unflaggable ;-)

*comment removed*

Comment: I wasn't aware that I couldn't unupvote it... when I put my cursor over it, there wasn't an ability to click on anything. I initially wanted to put a custom flag asking to delete all the comments, but mucked that up as well. :P Thanks for removing it!

Comment: Hi Manish. One more thing you forgot - Upvoting a comment also has a *timelock* stuff associated with it (1 or 2 mins - I thinks so). We can't unupvote after a certain time :-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: Ah, that makes sense. Looks like even I can't flag/unupvote old comments -- and generally timed restrictions don't apply to mods. I'll edit the post

Comment: @Crazy Don't worry, I was [pretty awed](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22336/tricky-conservation-of-momentum-problem-find-the-ratio-of-the-carts-by-mass-per#comment51603_22340) when I [first learned of it](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22336/tricky-conservation-of-momentum-problem-find-the-ratio-of-the-carts-by-mass-per#comment51598_22336) as well :). Most of these powers make sense though--we're supposed to be able to edit any comment anytime, so no point selectively blocking us from editing our own. Ditto for chat.